# Each XML fragment file from the shared library loads with a separate HTTP call instead of using the contents of the preload file

Tags: sapui5

I have my fragments in BSP *zshared*. I'm reusing them from *zapp1* by `dependencies`/ `sap.ui.core.Fragment` on UI5 1.52.
I can see that the library-preload.js file is loaded and contains my *zshared* fragments. Despite that, each fragment still gets loaded with a separate HTTP call.

Does anyone know how to avoid it?

Comment: Are the paths registered correctly?

Comment: Yes, the paths for zshared are correct as the library-preload.js has the correct contents and the fragments are loaded and working. For some reason, they are just loaded one file by one.